# Integral, left-hand sum

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Could anyone explain why my first answer is wrong? what I did was

delta x = 10/5 = 2
$$ 2(2^2+1)+2(4^2+1)+2(6^2+1)+2(8^2+1) = 248 $$

and the second answer was 
$$ 2(2^2+1)+2(4^2+1)+2(6^2+1)+2(8^2+1)+ 2(10^2+1) = 450 $$ but I put 590  by mistake and I got it right now.

and how to know if they are overestimate or underestimate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you used a right-hand sum rather than left-hand. Start with the function evaluated at $x=0$, and you should get $2(0^2+1)+2(2^2+1)+2(4^2+1)+2(6^2+1)+2(8^2+1)=250$.

To determine whether the estimate is an underestimation or overestimation, just take the derivative of the function and you'll see that the rate of change is positive, implying that the first example (which is a left-hand sum) is an underestimation.

Comment: Thanks, regarding over and under estimation. Did you mean that I will take the derivative of the x^2+1 ? or what exactly

Comment: Yep, taking the derivative of $x^2+1$ will give you an idea of the behaviour of the function whose definite integral you're approximating. In this case, the function is increasing for all $x>0$. Graphing this, you'll see that the rectangles you're using to approximate the area between the function and the x-axis (when using a left-hand sum) leave some of the area uncovered. But if it were a right-hand sum, the value of the definite integral would be overestimated. Note that this only works for monotonic functions.